# How do I update component A's state when component B receives input from user and stores it in database? How do I fetch data for A from DB?

Tags: database, reactjs, redux

I am new to React, trying to figure out how to update Component A's state when Component B receives information from a user. Component B is a form for a user to fill out, which then gets stored in a database(Heroku DB, using Postico). The info received from user must be reflected on Component A on my landing page. How do I fetch data from Database and show it on Component A as soon as the user clicks 'submit' button on Component B? I have included a link to my github (https://github.com/beckinfonet/blueskyproject) if you need to see my source code.

This is what needs to get updated, specifically where I left comments "needs update here"

Component A:

```
class CampaignDescription extends Component {
    constructor(props){
      super(props);

      this.state = {

      }
    }

    render() {

const { campaign } [enter image description here][1]= this.props

      return (
  <div>         
      <Card style={{
          width: '40vw',
          marginLeft: '30px',
          titleStyle: 'red'
          }}>
      <CardHeader
          title="URL Avatar"
          subtitle="Avatar Subtitle"
          avatar={require('../src/resources/collegefootball.JPG')}
          padding='50px'

      />
      <CardMedia 
          overlay={<CardTitle 
          title='campaign_title' //  1. **NEEDS UPDATE HERE**
          subtitle='end_date'/>} //  2. **NEEDS UPDATE HERE**
      >

        <img src="https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/blue-sky-project.appspot.com/o/profilePictures%2FIMG.JPG?alt=media&token=75d5e3f3-207c-4f6d-9563-9726f1c8f8e4" alt="" />
      </CardMedia>
         <CardTitle title="amount_needed UPDATE NEEDED HERE"  subtitle="city_state_of_residence UPDATE NEEDED HERE" />
         <CardText >

         campaign_description  should be here    UPDATE NEEDED HERE

              <SweetProgress />
      </CardText>
         <CardActions>
         <FlatButton label="DONATE" />
         <FlatButton label="SHARE!" />
      </CardActions>
    </Card>
  </div>
      )}
};

function mapStateToProps(state){
  return state;
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { changeCampaignTitle })(CampaignDescription)
```

Component B:
**

```
export class TextFieldForm extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
            campaign_title: '',
            end_date: '',
            amount_needed: '',
            city_state_of_residence: '',
            campaign_description: ''
    }
  }
  render(){
    const { campaign_title, 
            end_date, amount_needed, 
            city_state_of_residence, 
            campaign_description } = this.state**


return(

      <div style={{
        width: '190px',
        marginLeft: '470px'
    }}>

      <TextField 
        hintText="Title of campaign"
        onChange={(event) => {
          this.setState({campaign_title: event.target.value})}}
      /><br />

       <TextField
        hintText="When will the campaign end?"
        onChange={(event) => {
          this.setState({end_date: event.target.value})}}
      /><br />

      <TextField
        hintText="Please specify amount"
        floatingLabelText="How much do you need?"
        onChange={(event) => {
          this.setState({amount_needed: event.target.value})}}
        /><br /> 

      <TextField
        hintText="City and State of residence"
        floatingLabelText="Specify your city and state"
        floatingLabelFixed={true}
        onChange={(event) => {
          this.setState({city_state_of_residence: event.target.value})}}
      /><br />
  <div>{this.props.campaign} </div>
      <TextField
      onChange={(event) => {
        this.setState({campaign_description: event.target.value})}}
        hintText="Message to your contributors"
        floatingLabelText="Description of your campaign"
        multiLine={true}
        rows={2}
  /> 

  <br />
  <button 
    className="campaignBtn btn btn-primary"
    type="button"

    onClick={ () => {
      this.props.changeCampaignTitle(campaign_title, 
                                     end_date, amount_needed, 
                                     city_state_of_residence, 
                                     campaign_description)
      console.log(this.props.allCampaign)}}>Submit</button>

    </div>
    )
  }

}

function mapStateToProps(state){
  console.log(state)
  return state;
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { changeCampaignTitle })(TextFieldForm)
```

This is my reducer:

```
import axios from 'axios';

const initialState = {
    allCampaign: [],
    isLoading: false,
    didError: false
}

const CAMPAIGN_PROCESS = 'CAMPAIGN_PROCESS';


export function changeCampaignTitle(
                    campaign_title, 
                    end_date, 
                    amount_needed, 
                    city_state_of_residence, 
                    campaign_description
                ){
    // console.log('test')
    return {
        type: CAMPAIGN_PROCESS,
        payload: axios
            .post('/api/campaigns', { 
                    campaign_title, 
                    end_date, amount_needed, 
                    city_state_of_residence, 
                    campaign_description })
    }
}

function userReducer( state = initialState, action ) {
    switch(action.type){
        case `${CAMPAIGN_PROCESS}_PENDING`: 
          return Object.assign({}, state, {
             isLoading: true

        } );
        case `${CAMPAIGN_PROCESS}_FULFILLED`:
          return Object.assign({}, state, {
             isLoading: false,
             allCampaign: action.payload
      });

       case `${CAMPAIGN_PROCESS}_REJECTED`:
          return Object.assign({}, state, {
             isLoading: false,
             didError: true
      });
        return [...state, action.payload]

        default: return state;
    }
}

export default userReducer;
```

This is the function I am using to make a request to DB:

```
module.exports = {
    create: ( req, res, next ) => {
        const dbInstance = req.app.get( 'db' );
        const { campaign_title, 
                end_date, amount_needed, 
                city_state_of_residence, 
                campaign_description } = req.body

        dbInstance.create_campaign([ campaign_title, 
                                     end_date, amount_needed, 
                                     city_state_of_residence, 
                                     campaign_description ])
            .then(result => {return res.json(result)})
            // BE SURE TO RETURN RES.JSON IN YOUR .THEN PART OF YOUR APPLICATION
            .catch(console.log);
    },
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why make a separate request to DB to fetch data, when the user has already filled out the data. Store all the information (campaign_title, end-date, amount-needed)etc. in the redux store and display it using connect and mapStateToProps in Component A. I am not sure when you will be showing Component A's data, but in all likelihood it will be on some other screen.

If it matters, in componentDidMount of component A call the fetch api to retreive the latest data.